# Voting on questions, answers and comments does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sidebar is all messed up.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/858/sidebar-is-all-messed-up)

Voting on askubuntu.com is completely broken. Each time I try to press the vote buttons on questions, answers and comments, I get an error:

> An error has occurred - please retry your request.
>   (click on this box to dismiss)

Using Firebugs netpanel, I found out that the vote request is not properly processed.

https://askubuntu.com/posts/2636/vote/2 gets redirected to https://askubuntu.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/2636/vote/2.

This behavior was first observed while trying to vote on [What is the difference between Network Manager and 'ifconfig' 'ifup', etc?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1786/6969). Voting does still work on stackoverflow.com.

Browser: Mozilla Firefox 3.6.13. User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; nl; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13

---

### Comments

Cleared my cache, to no avail. Could it be related to a programming error that caused the sidebar being messed up? Are you able to vote? I can't even submit a comment.

---

Clearing single __qca, ubuntuuser or all cookies didn't help. Changing the User-Agent string to Google Chrome using [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/) does not change the situation.

---

Although Google Chrome works, with the same User-Agent string and cookies from meta.askubuntu.com and askubuntu.com cleared, the bug does still exist. The used User-Agent string is: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.10 Chromium/9.0.597.45 Chrome/9.0.597.45 Safari/534.13.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'd suggest [clearing your cache](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache)?

Comment: Possibly Related to: [Sidebar is all messed up.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/858/sidebar-is-all-messed-up)

Comment: Using Google Chrome 9.0.597.45 works fine. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team StackOverflow is aware of this and should be patching it shortly!

Comment: I can vote up and comment... it's fixed, thanks!